# Prove $ P_{n+1} + _{n+2} ≤ _1\times_2\times\cdots\times_n$ for $n\geq3$. $P_n$ is the $n$-th prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

As part of one of my assignment in CS degree, I have to prove this question:

> $P_n$ is the $n$-th prime. Prove 
>   $$P_{n+1} + P_{n+2} \leq P_1\times P_2\times\cdots\times P_n$$
>   for $n\geq3$.

I was trying to apply [Bonse's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality), which indicate
$$P_{n+1}^2\lt P_1\times P_2\times\cdots\times P_n$$
for $n\geq4$, but with no successes.
Any help will be grateful.

Comment: What is Bone's theorem? Anyway either your citations or the "theorem" is wrong:
$P_{3+1}^2 = 49 < 2\times 3 \times 5$ is obviously false.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write for n>=5.

Comment: Why don't you follow the comment at your [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317694/lets-p-be-a-prime-numbers-prove-p-n1-n2-%E2%89%A4-1%E2%88%99-2%E2%88%99%E2%88%99%E2%88%99-n-for) question and explain your notations? Can you please give a reference for Bone's theorem?

Comment: It was close for "off site topic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonse's inequality is true for $n\geq4$ (it is widely accepted that $1$ is not a prime, thus $p_1=2$). Also for $n\geq4 \Rightarrow p_n>3$. What we have is
$$p_1\cdot p_2\cdot ... \cdot p_n > p_{n+1}^2>3p_{n+1}=2p_{n+1}+p_{n+1} > ...$$
Now, the key point is [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), $2p_{n+1}>p_{n+2}$, thus
$$...>p_{n+2}+p_{n+1}$$
You will have to check $n=3$ case manually.

Comment: How do you know that $p_{n+1}^2>3p_{n+1}$. It does make sense but how do you prove it.

Comment: @RaphaelGozlan because $p_n>3,n\geq3 \Rightarrow p_{n+1}>3$, now multiply left and right sides by $p_{n+1}$ (which is a positive number).

Answer (score 1):

Apply Bonse at $P_{n+1}$ and at $P_{n+2}$ and get
$$P_{n+1}^2+P_{n+2}^2 \le (P_1 \cdots P_n) \cdot (1+P_{n+1}). \tag{1}$$

**A re-do of finish** (wrong before). Let $Q$ be the prime product which is the first factor on the right of $(1)$. Also let $p=P_{n+1},q=P_{n+2}.$ Then dividing $(1)$ by $(1+p)$ we have
$$\frac{p^2+q^2}{1+p} \le Q. \tag{2}$$ So it will be enough to show $p+q$ is bounded above by the left side of $(2).$ That is, 
$p+q+pq+q^2 \le p^2+q^2,$ or
$$ p+q+pq \le q^2.$$ Since $p,q$ are odd primes, if we put $q=x$ then $p \le x-2$ and the left side is at most (replacing $p$ by $q-2$) $x^2-2,$ bounded above as desired by $q^2=x^2.$

Comment: Could you elaborate and explain please, I didn't quit understand.

Comment: Bonse's inequality [is true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*3*5*7+-+11%5E2) for $n=4$ (because $p_1 = 2$)

Comment: how did you get from $$P_{n+1}^2+P_{n+2}^2 \le (P_1 \cdots P_n) \cdot (1+P_{n+1}).$$ to $$P_{n+1}+P_{n+2} \le \frac{P_{n+1}^2+P_{n+2}^2}{P_{n+1}}.$$ then how do I get from there to $$P_1\times P_2\times\cdots\times P_n$$

Comment: @RaphaelGozlan I realized later that I didn't finish it right. Found a correct finish and will include it.

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand's postulate alone suffices.

$p_{n+1}<2p_n,\ p_{n+2}<2p_{n+1}<4p_n$

$p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}<6p_n$

$p_1\cdot p_2=6$, so $p_n\# \ge 6p_n$ for $n\ge 3$

Ergo $p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}<p_n\# $